# Using Charts on Prince Library

Tags: princexml

I am running some tests on Prince version 14.

I am wondering if someone here successfully displayed a chart on a generated PDF?

I tried different libraries and still, it does not display the charts I'm trying to generate in it.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? It's probably something related to JavaScript. The DocRaptor API, which uses Prince in the background, has a documentation page on charts and JavaScript capability: https://help.docraptor.com/en/articles/1067614-troubleshooting-javascript-frameworks-charting-libraries

Answer (score -1):

I think https://www.princexml.com/releases/14/ link is useful for you